# Issue with a function that calculates the sum of positive elements after a negative element

Tags: python

I am working on a Python function that takes an array as input and returns the maximum sum of positive elements that come right after a negative element:

```py
def some(arr):
    som = 0
    startSum = False
    ta = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < 0:
            som = 0
            startSum = True
        elif startSum == True:
            som += arr[i]
            ta.append(som)
    if len(ta) == 0:
        return 0
    return max(ta)
```

For example, when I input the array `[1, -2]`, the function returns `0`, but the correct output should be `-1`.

How can I modify my function to handle this situation correctly?

Comment: 0 is the right answer, there are no positive numbers after a negative number.

Comment: Why would `-1` be the correct output? Please clarify.

Comment: there are only one negative elements, so return -1)

Comment: And how does that relate to "the maximum sum of positive elements that come right after a negative element"?

Comment: Either you haven't shared the requirements clearly, or you haven't understood them. Having more than one test case might be a good idea.

Comment: Your description of what your function should do is inconsistent with your example and your explanation of your example.  Your description says you want to add all sequences of positive numbers that follow a negative number, returning the maximum sum.  Such a sum will obviously always be non-negative.  But your example suggests that what you want is something like the number of negative numbers, negated, which makes no sense and has nothing to do with the task you described.  It sounds like you don't understand the problem, and don't really know what you want.

Comment: This `[1, -2]` is a list. An array would be: `from array import array array('l', [1, -2])`.

Comment: Your example input `[1, -2]` contains only one negative number, and it is the last number, so there aren't any numbers **after** it.  Please explain **why** you expect the sum here to be -1.

Comment: If the table contains one negative number, you must return -1

Comment: @XMehdi01 Did it not occur to you to mention that in your post?  Please edit your post to include a complete, unambiguous description of *exactly* what it should do.  Your last comment implies that you need to fist count the number of negative numbers, and if there is only one, then return -1.  Otherwise return the maximum sum as you originally described.  So `[1, 2, -5, 7, 3]` should return `-1` ("If the table contains one negative number, you must return -1").  But `[1, 2, -5, 7, 3, -2]` should return `10`.  Is that correct?  Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the comments, what about this function?

```
def some(arr):
    count = sum(num < 0 for num in arr)
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    if count == 1:
        return -1
    som = 0
    startSum = False
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < 0:
            if startSum:
                return som
            startSum = True
        elif startSum == True:
            som += arr[i]
    return som
```

Basically i start by counting how many negatives number are present and based on the count i return the value

`1 negative => return -1`

`0 negatives => return 0`

Otherwise return the sum with the code you provided with a little modification

```
if arr[i] < 0:
    if startSum:
        return som
    startSum = True
```

So that if you find another negative number in the list you stop and return the sum you got until that number

Keep in mind that you could achieve the same thing by running no for loop and using the sum method directly like this:

```
def some(arr):
    count = sum(num < 0 for num in arr)
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    if count == 1:
        return -1
    # We find the first negative number and doing +1 to get the number after that one
    start_index = arr.index(next(num for num in arr if num < 0)) + 1
    # we find the next negative number after the above one, otherwise we return len(arr)
    end_index = arr.index(next((num for num in arr[start_index:] if num < 0), len(arr)))
    # return the sum of the array containing only the numbers in the middle
    return sum(arr[start_index:end_index])
```

Edit after the last comment (version where we calculate the max sum of the number after a negative one and return that sum):

```
def some(arr):
    count = sum(num < 0 for num in arr)
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    if count == 1:
        return -1
        
    max_sum = float('-inf')
    start_index = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < 0:
            max_sum = max(max_sum, sum(arr[start_index:i]))
            start_index = i + 1
    max_sum = max(max_sum, sum(arr[start_index:]))
    return max_sum if max_sum != float('-inf') else 0
```

Comment: it returns 0 but expected
arr=[10, -4, -9, 10, -10, 8, -8, 2, -7, 3], expected: 10
arr=[2, 1, 2, 9, 9, 0, 5, 9, 0, 6], expected: -1
arr=[-8, -8, 3, -1, 3, 10, 8, 9, -8, 3], expected: 30

Comment: Instead of `len([num for num in arr if num < 0])`, it would be better to use `sum(num < 0 for num in arr)`, which avoids the creation of a potentially large temporary list.

Comment: Sorry i think i don't understand

Why in the first example you expected 10? The first negative number is -4, but after the -4 you got another negative number.

In the second example you have no negative number, you commented above that you wanted -1 in the case there was only 1 negative number

Third example is like the first one

Comment: @TomKarzes You are right, but using your approach you wont be able to know how many negatives number are inside the array. I though he wanted 0 if the are only positive number, -1 if there is only one negative number otherwise the sum

Comment: @Fanto No, `sum(num < 0 for num in arr)` exactly gives you the number of negative values in the array. It serves the exact same purpose and is more efficient.

Comment: @Unmitigated Yeah you are right, my bad. Code updated, thanks

Comment: in this example [-1,6,-2,3,5,-7] between -1 and -2 there are 6, and between -1 and -2 there are 3 and 5, so return 8 not 6

Comment: @XMehdi01 Check the last version of the code posted in my answer. Is that what you are looking for? the max sum of the numbers after a negative one

Comment: between -1 and -2 there are no elements, so return 0

Comment: @XMehdi01 I apologize, but I'm afraid I won't be able to provide any further assistance. I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're looking for, and it seems that the requirements of the question keep changing with each comment you post.

Comment: Yes, this is a question that caused me to lose my productivity